# Decidability of Narcissistic Language Using Turing Machines

Tags: turing-machines

I've been working on decidability practice problems and I came across this one in a practice problem set from the textbook An Introduction to Computational Techniques. I know the steps for how to prove a language is undecidable by constructing a Turing Machine which shows that the language is not recursive. However, I'm not sure how to prove that this language is decidable. Does anyone know how to solve this?

The question is:

> Prove that the following language is decidable:
> $$ \{⟨M ⟩ \mid L(M ) = \{⟨N ⟩ : ⟨N ⟩ = ⟨M ⟩\text{ or }L(N ) = \{⟨M ⟩\}\}$$

Comment: Your language might be empty.

Comment: Who are the authors of the textbook in which this problem was found?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus would the non-empty set $\{ \langle M \rangle \mid L(M)=\{ \langle M \rangle \}$ be contained in this language?

Comment: A non-empty set cannot be contained in an empty set.

Comment: I am aware, I'm questioning whether it really _is_ empty.